# Match multiple instances of mysteriously ordered complex regular expression non-capturing groups

Tags: c#, regex, parsing, .net-3.5

## TL;DR

I am parsing a report using C# regex, MultiLine enabled, processing the whole file using a single (complex) regex pattern with named groups. (And CaptureCollection.)

Sections of my report appear out of order or are missing in a way I cannot predict.

How do I match them regardless of the order they appear in?

## Preface

I am parsing a report using regular expressions in C# (.Net 3.5) using System.Text.RegularExpressions. One section of the report looks like this:

```
     Section Z              0 __ base 10
                            2 __ 19/04 20:06:39
                            2 __ 19/04 20:15:49
                          1.8 __ 19/04 20:09:35
                          1.6 __ 19/04 20:07:01
                          1.6 __ 19/04 20:08:29
     Section 7            0.8 __ base 10
                            8 __ 18/04 21:03:01
                          7.3 __ 18/04 21:02:17
                          3.7 __ 19/04 08:41:09
                          3.4 __ 19/04 00:13:08
                          3.3 __ 18/04 21:02:50
     Section C              0 __ base 10
                         19.7 __ 19/04 10:25:06
                         11.1 __ 19/04 10:15:01
                          8.8 __ 19/04 10:14:50
                          7.2 __ 19/04 19:51:37
                          6.1 __ 19/04 14:19:47
```

My regex matches the text file as a whole, using the options `(?mx)` (MultiLine, IgnorePatternWhitespace). Because the statistic section has sub-statistics for each, I have resorted to manually crafting each section's (optional `?`) non-capturing group (`(?:match_this_text)`) and putting them in the pattern in the order I thought they were occurring, such as the following:

```
(?mx) #Turn on options multiline, ignore whitespace.
(?: # base 10 statistic sections
    (?:
        [\s-[\n\r]]*(?i:Section\sZ)\s+(?<base10_SectionZ>\d+\.\d|\d+)\s__\sbase\s10
        (?:\r?\n)+
        (?:\s+(?<base10_SectionZ_instance>\d+\.\d|\d+)\s__\s(?<base10_SectionZ_instance_time>\d\d/\d\d\s\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)(?:\r?\n)+)+
    )?
    (?:
        [\s-[\n\r]]*(?i:Section\s7)\s+(?<base10_Section7>\d+\.\d|\d+)\s__\sbase\s10
        (?:\r?\n)+
        (?:\s+(?<base10_Section7_instance>\d+\.\d|\d+)\s__\s(?<base10_Section7_instance_time>\d\d/\d\d\s\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)(?:\r?\n)+)+
    )?
    (?:
        [\s-[\n\r]]*(?i:Section\sC)\s+(?<base10_SectionC>\d+\.\d|\d+)\s__\sbase\s10
        (?:\r?\n)+
        (?:\s+(?<base10_SectionC_instance>\d+\.\d|\d+)\s__\s(?<base10_SectionC_instance_time>\d\d/\d\d\s\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)(?:\r?\n)+)+
    )?
)
```

The first line of each section's non-capturing group matches the 'section header', the second line matches the newline between the header and the statistic instances, and the third matches the individual statistic instances (repeating, *n* number of instances).

## The Problem

The program that generates this report, depending on which version is running, outputs each section (e.g. Section Z, Section 7, Section C) in different orders, and certain sections are missing in certain circumstances. When I ran it against a second test file, it failed because the sections were out of order.

Thus, section C could occur before Section Z, but the regex pattern is expecting Z to occur before C.

Basically, I want the same regex to match and extract (using the named groups above) the same data regardless of the order the sections appear in, such that it matches both the test data above, and this test data:

```
     Section 7            0.8 __ base 10
                            8 __ 18/04 21:03:01
                          7.3 __ 18/04 21:02:17
                          3.7 __ 19/04 08:41:09
                          3.4 __ 19/04 00:13:08
                          3.3 __ 18/04 21:02:50
     Section C              0 __ base 10
                         19.7 __ 19/04 10:25:06
                         11.1 __ 19/04 10:15:01
                          8.8 __ 19/04 10:14:50
                          7.2 __ 19/04 19:51:37
                          6.1 __ 19/04 14:19:47
     Section Z              0 __ base 10
                            2 __ 19/04 20:06:39
                            2 __ 19/04 20:15:49
                          1.8 __ 19/04 20:09:35
                          1.6 __ 19/04 20:07:01
                          1.6 __ 19/04 20:08:29
```

Comment: Read files to memory, sort sections in each of them and then do your stuff on it...

Comment: Kudos for the neat regex layout and use of multiline strings and comments!!

Comment: My eventual solution to this was not to use a single massive regex against the entire file as a string. Instead I enumerate the lines, and use a stack of parent-child (section-instance) patterns to perform a recursive search, by line, of whether the line is a section start marker. If it is, it tries the child (instance) pattern on the next line, and if that works, it tries the child again on the next line. If the child fails on the next line, it pops the stack until it finds a match. The root of the stack is (.*), and if it hits root (goes through all possible patterns), it ignores the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't give the regex engine the option to match nothing.
It will roam around finding a lot of 'nothing' before it finds an optional something.

**edit**

*If you just want a block match* (any order, but sequential) something like this will work.
Your way now, with modifications:

```
(?:
   (?: Section ...  (?<sec_7> 7)
   )
 | (?: Section ...  (?<sec_C> C)
   )?
 | (?: Section ...  (?<sec_Z> Z)
   )
)
(?: Section ...  (?!\k<sec_7>) (?<sec_7>  7) )?
(?: Section ...  (?!\k<sec_C>) (?<sec_C>  C) )?
(?: Section ...  (?!\k<sec_Z>) (?<sec_Z>  Z) )?
```

If it can be factored, then this way:

```
(?: Section ...  (?<sec_a>(?:7|C|Z) )
(?: Section ...  (?<sec_b>(?!\k<sec_a>)(?:7|C|Z)  )?
(?: Section ...  (?<sec_c>(?!\k<sec_a>|\k<sec_b>)(?:7|C|Z)  )?
#
# Then after match check <sec_a/b/c> for its value
```

*If you don't care about a block match:*
Your case revolves around just an OR condition.
So, it could be as easy as this:

```
# base 10 statistic sections
    (?: ..)
  |
    (?: ..)
  |
    (?: ..)
```

Where each match in 'base 10' section match has to be checked in a while loop as

```
Match m = Regex.Match(input, regex, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
while (m.Success)
{
   if (m.Groups["base10_Section7"].Success)  {    }
   else
   if (m.Groups["base10_SectionZ"].Success)  {    }
   else
   if (m.Groups["base10_SectionC"].Success)  {    }
   m = m.NextMatch();
}
```

Even this can be reduced. For instance 7,Z,C can be combined in a single chunk.
This will leave the OR (|) for other distinct items to match, like say, 'base 2',
or any other form. One form will match. It has to be checked anyway.

```
string input = @"
    Section Z              0 __ base 10
                           2 __ 19/04 20:06:39
                           2 __ 19/04 20:15:49
                         1.8 __ 19/04 20:09:35
                         1.6 __ 19/04 20:07:01
                         1.6 __ 19/04 20:08:29
    Section P           16.1 __ base 2
    Section 7            0.8 __ base 10
                           8 __ 18/04 21:03:01
                         7.3 __ 18/04 21:02:17
                         3.7 __ 19/04 08:41:09
                         3.4 __ 19/04 00:13:08
                         3.3 __ 18/04 21:02:50
    Section C              0 __ base 10
                        19.7 __ 19/04 10:25:06
                        11.1 __ 19/04 10:15:01
                         8.8 __ 19/04 10:14:50
                         7.2 __ 19/04 19:51:37
                         6.1 __ 19/04 14:19:47
    Section r           49.2 __ Base 2
";

string regex = @"
   # base 10 statistic sections
       (?:
         [\s-[\n\r]]*(?i:Section\s(?<base10_Section>Z|7|C)\s+(?<Base10>\d+\.\d|\d+)\s__\sbase)\s10
         (?:\r?\n)+
         (?:\s+(?<Instance>\d+\.\d|\d+)\s__\s(?<Time>\d\d/\d\d\s\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)(?:\r?\n)+)+
       )
     |  # Or, base 2 statistic sections
       (?:
         [\s-[\n\r]]*(?i:Section\s(?<base2_Section>R|P)\s+(?<Base2>\d+\.\d|\d+)\s__\sbase)\s2
         (?:\r?\n)+
       )
   # |  Or, something else

";

Match m = Regex.Match(input, regex, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
int matchCount = 0;
while (m.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nMatch " + (++matchCount) + "\n------------------");
    // Check base 10
    if (m.Groups["base10_Section"].Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Section (base10)  '" + m.Groups["base10_Section"] + "'  =  '" + m.Groups["Base10"] + "'\n");

        int count = m.Groups["Instance"].Captures.Count;
        // Instance
        for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
            System.Console.WriteLine("    Instance (" + j + ") =  '" + m.Groups["Instance"].Captures[j] + "' ");
        // Time
        for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
            System.Console.WriteLine("    Time(" + j + ") =  '" + m.Groups["Time"].Captures[j] + "' ");
        // Combined ..
        for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
            System.Console.WriteLine("    Instance,Time  (" + j + ") =  '" +
                                          m.Groups["Instance"].Captures[j] + "' __ '" +
                                          m.Groups["Time"].Captures[j] + "' ");
    }
    else
    // Check base 2
    if (m.Groups["base2_Section"].Success)
        Console.WriteLine("Section (base2)  '" + m.Groups["base2_Section"] + "'  =  '" + m.Groups["Base2"] + "'\n");

    m = m.NextMatch();
}
```

Comment: This most closely describes what I originally was looking for, which was the ability to match 'a section, no matter what order it shows up in'. I should have specified that I was looking for 'a section of an unknown set, no matter what order it shows up in', because I can never guarantee the naming convention of a section or whether it will show up. This (and others) also took me down the path of realization that one giant regex was not appropriate, and that I would have to do deeper in-code parsing.

Answer (score 1):

You just want to capture each section?

Wouldn't this work? `(Section ..*(?:\r.*){0,5})`

http://regexr.com?30nfd

Comment: That was my though exactly. Then validate that the correct sections are in there afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that it might be better to have a couple of different regex's than one giant regex in this case.  I would [`File.RealAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx) and then loop through each line with an  [`If String.Contains("Section")`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx).  If it contains section, create a new section object, run a section regex to populate the new section object (section name and section data).  If it does not contain *section* run another regex for additional section data and append it to the current section object.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the \G option to anchor each expression to the previous result, that way you still ensure that nothing is between your sections which is unwanted.

And you can use the more generic expression for a section:

```
(?mx) #Turn on options multiline, ignore whitespace.
\G
(?: # base 10 statistic sections
    (?:
        [\s-[\n\r]]*(?i:Section\s(Z|7|C))\s+(?<base10_Section>\d+\.\d|\d+)\s__\sbase\s10
        (?:\r?\n)+
        (?:\s+(?<base10_Section_instance>\d+\.\d|\d+)\s__\s(?<base10_Section_instance_time>\d\d/\d\d\s\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)(?:\r?\n)+)+
    )
)
```

Afterwards verify that a section wasn't duplicated or missing. [See it in action](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=94c42016-65a7-4849-85b6-76043d59528d).